# Как использовать ЧПУ для запланированных записей?

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую!

Подскажите, как выводить ЧПУ запланированных записей?

`the_permalink()` не подходит, т.к. согласно [коду](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) состояния постов `'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft', 'future'` будут "ugly" (не ЧПУ).

Comment: А вам зачем permalink записи, которая нигде, кроме админки, не существует?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, затем, что эти записи выводятся в мероприятиях, как "будущие" =)

Comment: Я уже так и понял. Ну тогда бы я взял код the_permalink(), переименовал в my_permalink(), вставил этот код в тему или свой плагин. А в коде выкинул проверку на pending и формировал бы ссылку по общим правилам wp, как для опубликованной записи.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, это самое очевидное решение) просто мало ли есть какие-то стандартные пути для решения данной проблемы, не особо хотел дублировать код.

Comment: В коде нет никаких хуков, позволющих в него "влезть". Последний хук "на выходе" ничего не даст. Всё равно своим кодом надо ссылку формировать.